# What is the meaning of "Cómo olvidar tus locuras" in a song lyric?

Tags: traducción

I'm translating [*Nunca Te Olvidaré* by Enrique Iglesias](https://youtu.be/pRrjt4htXlE?t=1m44s) to English. The lyrics include the following line:

> Cómo olvidar tus locuras

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that there's no direct/very accurate English translation for the word "locuras".

> How could I forget "tus locuras"

I can think of "your crazy things", "your antics", "your peculiar acts", but neither seem to grasp the original meaning fully.

I'm interested to know what do you think would be the translation here.

Comment: What about *follies*? Obviously he doesn't mean madness or insanity. Even more: here *locuras* may imply sexual desire.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a translation to a language that is not Spanish.

Comment: @enxaneta "folly" stands for _"the state or quality of being foolish; lack of understanding or sense"_ or _"a foolish action, practice, idea, etc.; absurdity"_, so I don't think it's the word here...

Comment: Note that as @rsanchez says, we are not experts in the English language. We can help you understand what the sentence means in Spanish, but the final translation will be up to you. You should reword your question to reflect this and ask for the meaning of "tus locuras" instead of asking directly for a translation.

Comment: @rsanchez this is an acceptable question as it wants to understand the meaning of an spanish figure, also don't forget that translation is an acceptable tag for the site and another of the goals of the site is to help others understand spanish

Comment: @Mike OP comments show that he already knows the meaning, and he's looking for a precise English equivalent. That's a question for an English forum.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oxford Dictionary

**[craziness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/craziness)**

> Mad, wild, or erratic behaviour or nature.
>
> ‘he loves me and all of my craziness’

**[antics](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antics)**

> Foolish, outrageous, or amusing behaviour.

According to the D.R.A.E

[**locura**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NYYDU9d)

> 1. f. Privación del juicio o del uso de la razón.
> 2. f. Acción inconsiderada o gran desacierto.
> 3. f. Acción que, por su carácter anómalo, causa sorpresa.
> 4. f. Exaltación del ánimo o de los ánimos, producida por algún afecto u otro incentivo.

**Antics** is one of your proposals and you have discarded **craziness** in the comments. This last term usually is the one that you use to translate **locura**. As you can observe, locura in Spanish may imply both senses: mental illness (1) and a sort of amusing behaviour (4).
I think that it's the correct translation in this case: **locura = craziness**.

Notice the example included in the Oxford Dictionary: *he loves me and all of my craziness*. That phrase does not imply mental illness but some sort of wild or extravagant behaviour. It's exactly the same sense expressed in the quoted lyrics.

Comment: I like this answer and btw in the lyrics it is not clear if "locuras' is about "amusing behavior" or "crazy, insane behavior" Enrique simply says "como olvidar tus locuras" and the surrounding sentences (context) does not make clear what kind of "locuras" he is talking about. (However what he does [with his hand](https://youtu.be/pRrjt4htXlE?t=1m44s) implies insanity)

Answer (score 1):

The basic translation is:

> How could one forget your insanities? Your schemes? Your madness?

The phrase could be used in the context of a friend reuniting with another after a long time.  One might say something like "I assumed you had forgotten me", and the other would answer "How could I forget your craziness?!" This could refer to something like an eccentric lifestyle, or a reckless one, something extraordinary, strange, and possibly extreme.

It's up for debate what exactly the translation for "locuras" would be in your provided context.

What *I'm* referring to are things such as quirks, or "crazy ways", or anything that a person does that paints them eccentric or peculiar.  I suppose the best, most formal, translation would be - **Idiosyncrasies**.

Comment: Does really "locuras" have the same meaning as "insanities" or "craziness"? Isn't it referring more to a playful and **a bit** crazy things _the persona_ does? To me, "insanities" or "craziness" sound like they're too close to a real insanity or craziness, if you know what I mean. Wouldn't a bit _lighter_ translation be better here?

Comment: How about: *your crazy ways*?

Comment: @Gustavson Interesting, but it's too sophisticated when you ask me.

Comment: I agree with @Gustavson In the question you said **I can think of "your crazy things",** and now **crazy ways** sounds _too sophisticated_ to you ? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Locura doesn't have the negative connotation in Spanish like in English.

The RAE defines `locura` as :

> Acción que, por su carácter anómalo, causa sorpresa.

Its translation would be :

> Action that, due to its anomalous nature, causes surprise.

In this aspect I would translate *locura* to "**eccentricity**" or "**eccentricities**".

Source: http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=NYYDU9d

Comment: But "locura" does have the negative connotation. What about the sense 1 that you have omitted?

Comment: I agree with @RubioRic that there is a negative meaning to "locura"but It doesn't matter for this question since the lyrics does not imply either negative or positive meanings.

Comment: I mean is not as negative as in english 
in english "craziness" and "madness" or "insanity"  are more related to a disease and angryness rather than the impulses of "locuras" in spanish 

a "locura" in spanish is not something made by someone clinically insane

Locura in spanish is more inclined to foolishness rather than insanity

Comment: @Mike Sorry, but you're wrong. In Spanish, as I've quoted in my answer, sense 1 denotes mental illness, insanity. The same word have four different senses, one of them is just foolishness as you say but it have other three senses.

Comment: you used the magical word there DENOTES.

Comment: I didn't know that it was a magical word. Denote, indicate, be a sign of, whatever you like most, it got a NEGATIVE sense related to mental state.

Comment: exactly, denotes means that i indicates in the word itself, but the connotation is on the indirect meaning and charge a word has.  i'm talking about CONNOTATION and in spanish "loco" is more about the unusual rather than a disease